# Convert base64string into image

Tags: c#

I m sending base64string from android app to webservice.
webservice converts that base64string into image again.
But i m getting below error from web service  while converting base64string into image again:

> "A generic error occurred in GDI+."  this error i m getting on server
>   only.

below is my code:

```
public string Base64ToImage(string base64String, string imgName)
{
    try
    {
        // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

        // Convert byte[] to Image
        ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
        System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms, true);

        image.Save(
            "D:\\apps\\PJP_TEST\\PJPTest\\Online\\ImageStorage\\" + imgName);

        return "Success";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }           
}
```

Comment: Why don't you write the conents of `imageBytes` to disk directly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A generic error occurred in GDI+. (Only if i try it on the server)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035346/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-only-if-i-try-it-on-the-server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess with 'server' you mean 'web server'. You probably have no rights to write in the folder `D:\apps\PJP_TEST\PJPTest\Online\ImageStorage`.

Check if the user that the application is running on has read and write access to the specified folder.

As said, it is easier to write the file directly:

```
File.WriteAllBytes( Path.Combine
                    ( @"D:\apps\PJP_TEST\PJPTest\Online\ImageStorage\"
                    , imgName
                    )
                  , imageBytes
                  );
```

Comment: You'd expect an IOException if that where the case, not a GDI+ error.

Comment: @AVee: Too bad. It really is.

Comment: You're right, it indeed throws a System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException. And yeah, I'd consider that pretty bad (but that doesn't make it less true).

Comment: @AVee: It is really obscure, but this is the error message you get when a file can't be written. I guess there is some low level Windows stuff going on in that method.

Comment: That's exactly what I just did :)

Comment: @PatrickHofman you are right. folder did not have read and write permissions. Thanx.